# Big Sur outline view expandable items broken

Tags: macos, appkit, nsoutlineview, macos-big-sur

I've started a new macOS project (currently on Big Sur beta 3), and the `NSOutlineView` nodes seem to be broken. Can't tell if this is me or the os.

[Here's a sample project](https://github.com/seanmrich/OutlineViewTest) that demonstrates the issue. And an image...

[image]

As you can see, the cell is overlapping the expansion chevrons. Clicking on either chevron restores the first row to the proper layout, but not the second. Also, the autosave methods `persistentObjectForItem` and `itemForPersistentObject` are never called.

The test project is super simple--all I did was add the `SourceView` component from the view library to the default app project and hook up the delegate/data source to the view controller. Also checked `Autosave Expanded Items` in IB and put a name in the `Autosave` field. Here's the entirety of the controller code:

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var outlineView: NSOutlineView?

    let data = [Node("First item", 1), Node("Second item", 2)]
}

extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        data[index]
    }
    
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        true
    }
    
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        item == nil ? data.count : 0
    }
    
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, byItem item: Any?) -> Any? {
        item
    }
    
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, persistentObjectForItem item: Any?) -> Any? {
        (item as? Node)?.id
    }
    
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, itemForPersistentObject object: Any) -> Any? {
        guard let id = object as? Int else { return nil }
        return data.first { $0.id == id }
    }
}


extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        guard let node = item as? Node else {
            preconditionFailure("Invalid data item \(item)")
        }
        let view = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: nodeCellIdentifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
        view?.textField?.stringValue = node.name
        view?.imageView?.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: node.icon, accessibilityDescription: nil)
        return view
    }
}


final class Node {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let icon: String
    
    init(_ name: String, _ id: Int, _ icon: String = "folder") {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.icon = icon
    }
}

private let nodeCellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("DataCell")
```

Any Mac developers left out there that can help?

Comment: Open your project, select the outline view and set the highlight property value to Regular (you have Source List here).

Comment: Thanks @zrzka, but this is intended to be in a sidebar, so `SourceList` is the style I'm looking for. You're right that changing the style fixes the issue so perhaps this confirms it's a bug? Also, autosave of the expansion state still doesn't get called

Comment: Do you happen to have some screenshot of what you'd like to achieve? What the end goal is? Because I don't see `outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isGroupItem item: Any)` implementation in your code, etc. Source list behaves a bit differently - for example - items are indented from the 3rd level, ... Usual structure is something like - top level = groups, 2nd level = not indented nodes with possible children, 3rd level = indented nodes, ...

Comment: Two levels Finder like - [gist](https://gist.github.com/zrzka/b2e98473cceff3d88564503a05c5c4a1) & [screenshot](https://cln.sh/fKjWiI). Three levels - same gist & [screenshot](https://cln.sh/jSrtOP). P.S. Don't force unwrap (`!`), I used it to quickly demonstrate what I meant.

Comment: Also _Jump to Definition_ of `NSOutlineView.SelectionHighlightStyle.sourceList` and read the comments there (they're not included in the docs).

Comment: Aha! Apparently the source list style doesn't support having no header groups. Once you add a group above the folder level (`isGroupItem` == true), layout is fixed and persisting of expansion state also starts working at all levels. Please put your solution in an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks @zrzka!

Comment: Also notice that the expansion chevron for a group is on the right side of the cell. This is what causes problems on the first level when the node is expandable, but not a group. I'll write an answer with more details tomorrow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Source list

What is a source list? It's [`NSOutlineView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineview) (which is a subclass of
[`NSTableView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview)) with a special
*treatment*. Finder screenshot:

[image]

To create a source list, all you have to do is to set the
[`selectionHighlightStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1526311-selectionhighlightstyle) property to
[`.sourceList`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/selectionhighlightstyle/sourcelist). The documentation says:

> The source list style of NSTableView. On 10.5, a light blue gradient is used to highlight selected rows.

What it does exactly? *Jump to Definition* in Xcode and read comments (not included in the docs):

> The source list style of NSTableView. On 10.10 and higher, a blur selection is used to highlight rows. Prior to that, a light blue gradient was used. Note: Cells that have a drawsBackground property should have it set to NO. Otherwise, they will draw over the highlighting that NSTableView does. Setting this style will have the side effect of setting the background color to the "source list" background color. Additionally in NSOutlineView, the following properties are changed to get the standard "source list" look: indentationPerLevel, rowHeight and intercellSpacing. After calling setSelectionHighlightStyle: one can change any of the other properties as required. In 10.11, if the background color has been changed from the "source list" background color to something else, the table will no longer draw the selection as a source list blur style, and instead will do a normal blue highlight.

Since you're on Big Sur, be aware that the `SelectionHighlightStyle.sourceList` is deprecated.
One should use [`style`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/3622475-style)
& [`effectiveStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/3622474-effectivestyle).

## Sample project

Xcode:

- New project

  - macOS & App (Storyboard & AppKit App Delegate & Swift)
- Main.storyboard

  - Add Source List control

    - Position & fix constraints
    - Set delegate & dataSource to ViewController
    - Enable Autosave Expanded Items
    - Set Autosave to whatever you want (I have `FinderLikeSidebar` there)

      - Choose wisely because the expansion state is saved in the user defaults
        under the `NSOutlineView Items FinderLikeSidebar` key
    - Create `@IBOutlet var outlineView: NSOutlineView!`
  - Add another Text Table Cell View (no image)

    - Set identifier to `GroupCell`
- ViewController.swift

  - Commented code below

### Screenshots

[image]

As you can see, it's almost Finder like - 2nd level is still indented. The reason
for this is that the *Documents* node is expandable (has children). I have them here to demonstrate autosaving.

Just remove them if you'd like to move all 2nd level nodes to the left.

[image]

### ViewController.swift code

There's not much to say about it except - read comments :)

```swift
import Cocoa

// Sample Node class covering groups & regular items
class Node {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let symbolName: String?
    let children: [Node]
    let isGroup: Bool
    
    init(id: Int, title: String, symbolName: String? = nil, children: [Node] = [], isGroup: Bool = false) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.symbolName = symbolName
        self.children = children
        self.isGroup = isGroup
    }
    
    convenience init(groupId: Int, title: String, children: [Node]) {
        self.init(id: groupId, title: title, children: children, isGroup: true)
    }
}

extension Node {
    var cellIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier {
        // These must match identifiers in Main.storyboard
        NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: isGroup ? "GroupCell" : "DataCell")
    }
}

extension Array where Self.Element == Node {
    // Search for a node (recursively) until a matching element is found
    func firstNode(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element? {
        for element in self {
            if try predicate(element) {
                return element
            }
            if let matched = try element.children.firstNode(where: predicate) {
                return matched
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSOutlineViewDelegate, NSOutlineViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var outlineView: NSOutlineView!
    
    let data = [
        Node(groupId: 1, title: "Favorites", children: [
            Node(id: 11, title: "AirDrop", symbolName: "wifi"),
            Node(id: 12, title: "Recents", symbolName: "clock"),
            Node(id: 13, title: "Applications", symbolName: "hammer")
        ]),
        Node(groupId: 2, title: "iCloud", children: [
            Node(id: 21, title: "iCloud Drive", symbolName: "icloud"),
            Node(id: 22, title: "Documents", symbolName: "doc", children: [
                Node(id: 221, title: "Work", symbolName: "folder"),
                Node(id: 221, title: "Personal", symbolName: "folder.badge.person.crop"),
            ])
        ]),
    ]
    
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        
        // Expanded items are saved in the UserDefaults under the key:
        //
        // "NSOutlineView Items \(autosaveName)"
        //
        // By default, this value is not present. When you expand some nodes,
        // an array with persistent objects is saved. When you collapse all nodes,
        // the array is removed from the user defaults (not an empty array,
        // but back to nil = removed).
        //
        // IOW there's no way to check if user already saw this source list,
        // modified expansion state, etc. We will use custom key for this
        // purpose, so we can expand group nodes (top level) when the source
        // list is displayed for the first time.
        //
        // Next time, we wont expand anything and will honor autosaved expanded
        // items.
        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "FinderLikeSidebarAppeared") == nil {
            data.forEach {
                outlineView.expandItem($0)
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "FinderLikeSidebarAppeared")
        }
    }
    
    // Number of children or groups (item == nil)
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        item == nil ? data.count : (item as! Node).children.count
    }
    
    // Child of a node or group (item == nil)
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        item == nil ? data[index] : (item as! Node).children[index]
    }
    
    // View for our node
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        guard let node = item as? Node,
              let cell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: node.cellIdentifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else {
            return nil
        }
        
        cell.textField?.stringValue = node.title
        
        if !node.isGroup {
            cell.imageView?.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: node.symbolName ?? "folder", accessibilityDescription: nil)
        }
        
        return cell
    }

    // Mark top level items as group items
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isGroupItem item: Any) -> Bool {
        (item as! Node).isGroup
    }
    
    // Every node is expandable if it has children
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        !(item as! Node).children.isEmpty
    }
    
    // Top level items (group items) are not selectable
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, shouldSelectItem item: Any) -> Bool {
        !(item as! Node).isGroup
    }
    
    // Object to save in the user defaults (NSOutlineView Items FinderLikeSidebar)
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, persistentObjectForItem item: Any?) -> Any? {
        (item as! Node).id
    }
    
    // Find an item from the saved object (NSOutlineView Items FinderLikeSidebar)
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, itemForPersistentObject object: Any) -> Any? {
        guard let id = object as? Int else { return nil }
        return data.firstNode { $0.id == id }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed implementation. I was hoping to implement autosaving of expanded items. Unfortunately, itemForPersistentObject gets read before my data is loaded from my filewrapper, and reloadData() does not trigger a second check so the whole 'autoexpanding' bit fails.